# I have two default routes on my Windows, from which interface are my packets leaving?

Tags: powershell, routes

I have two default routes on my Windows :

```
> Get-NetRoute -DestinationPrefix 0.0.0.0/0

ifIndex DestinationPrefix                              NextHop                                  RouteMetric ifMetric PolicyStore
------- -----------------                              -------                                  ----------- -------- -----------
14      0.0.0.0/0                                      0.0.0.0                                            0 1        ActiveStore
6       0.0.0.0/0                                      172.20.24.1                                      256 25       ActiveStore
```

From which interface are my packets leaving ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Get-NetRoute -DestinationPrefix "0.0.0.0/0"|Select IfIndex,DestinationPrefix,RouteMetric
```

It probably depend of -AutomaticMetric -InterfaceMetric parameter

Specifies the value for automatic metric calculation. Automatic metric determines whether TCP/IP automatically calculates a value for an interface metric that is based on the speed of the interface. The fastest interface has the lowest interface metric value. The acceptable values for this parameter are: Enable | Disable

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/set-netipinterface?view=windowsserver2022-ps

Comment: In my case, ifIndex has a RouteMetric of 0 so I can conclude that's the output interface, right ?

Comment: "The result is that whenever multiple default gateways are configured on multiple interfaces, the fastest interface will be used to forward traffic to its default gateway." If both interfaces are available, and will be the same RouteMetric , then top on list will be active interface. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc779696(v=ws.10)